# Any open source unicode ttf or otf font that I can use for my application?

Tags: android

any pointer would be helpful. I need a font with symbol character set

Comment: What do you mean by "unicode font"?  All OpenType fonts (either *.ttf or *.otf) use Unicode...

Comment: I meant font which has entire unicode character set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find lots of open source fonts at the [Open Font Library](http://openfontlibrary.org/) and at the [Google Font Directory](http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/) (I suppose most or all of the fonts on the latter are on the former too though).